# haxe macro catching of Context.parse() errors

Tags: exception, macros, haxe

At compile (macro) time, calling

```
Context.parse("a bad expression", somePos)
```

produces an error that *cannot* be caught in a try-catch block (**Edit:** this is wrong, see below). Is there a way to catch this error? Context.parseInlineString() doesn't seem to work either.

Others functions such as Context.typeExpr() have a similar problem.

**Edit:**
The *type* of catch was wrong. I did:

```
try {...}
catch (err:String) {...}
```

What you have to do:

```
try {...}
catch (err:Dynamic) {...}
```

Careful reading of the documentation explains this. This is different than Java for which there is one type of exception per error. In Haxe, *most* errors are strings, but there are some others like the one here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
import haxe.macro.*;

class Test {
    macro static function test() {
        try {
            Context.parse("a bad expression", Context.currentPos());
        } catch(e:Dynamic) {
            trace(e); //Test.hx:8: Missing ;
        }
        return macro {};
    }
    static function main() {
        test();
    }
}
```